# php dynamic link inquiry

Tags: php, dynamic

I have a scheduler on my website. This scheduler lets you select a date/time and once you do, it presents you with a form to fill out with your name, email, and message to fill in.

Once you complete the form, it gives the user a thank you message.

However, what I would also like it to do is provide the user with a dynamic link using php.

Here's my problem...

1. The link that I need generated dynamically is for a url that is different than the website the user is on.

For example, if my website is www.website.com, the dynamic link I need generated needs to point the user to a different web server (that is currently an IP Address).

In a perfect world, I would like the user to be able to:

1. Schedule an appointment (they can do this now)
2. Be presented with a form to fill out (They can do this now)
3. Be presented with a dynamic link that will take them to a different url.
4. Have the access to the link expire within 30 minutes.

My question is this...

1. Can the user be presented with a link that masks the IP address of the alternate web server?
2. Can the dynamic link be set to be active between a time that matches their scheduled request. For example, if the user selects a time to access the content at 11:00am, can the link generated be set to work between those times?

I know this is a lot and I don't expect anyone to work on this solution. I really would like to know if this is something that is possible. Or, if someone out there might have some better suggestions on how this might work?

Thank you all for your time/suggestions!

Comment: If it's an actual Client Side (HTML or JavaScript) link then the Client can see the URL. You could pass code into a cookie that you will have to match data in a database to allow the user to access within the next 30 minutes. You can use a JavaScript AJAX function to trigger PHP, using `header('LOCATION:youURLhere.php')`, so there is no link, but you would still have to protect the Client from just visiting `yourURLhere.php` with the matching cookie and database entry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

A table could be something like this

`user_id, appointment_date, url, time_submitted, unique_id`

For the dynamic link that is presented to said user, you could display something like `www.website.com/getLink/$unique_id`

Where `$unique_id` is a controller/action on your page that does a redirect to the URL in the database.

To determine if it's been 30 minutes, in your controller/action just put some logic:

```
if( ( $time_submitted + 1800 ) < time() ) { echo "time expired" } else { ... }
```

This is very basic, but should steer you in the right direction.

How to redirect:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php